# Duplicates location in Excel Online

Tags: excel

I have an online Excel workbook that I'm working on and I wanted to know if there is a way we could find out the exact location of where the text has duplicates.

I found a solution in the Excel downloaded macro workbook using VBA but I got to know Excel macro does not work online therefore I need to find a different solution to show the duplicates location in the online Excel workbook.

For instance, using conditional formatting I formatted it to show me it is a duplicate but I want it show the row number of where the duplicate is located. Does the Excel online offer any such feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a formula to retrieve the duplicates row = 1. helper column

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,$A2)>=2,ROW(A2),"")
```

then in the 2. helper column you add this formula:

```
=IF([@[row of duplicate]]<>"",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER([row of duplicate],([Name of Contact]=[@[Name of Contact]])*([row of duplicate]<>""),""),""),"")
```

Output is written to the first value with duplicates.
It joins the result of the row numbers by first filtering them by the name of the contact.

You need Excel 365 for this.

[image]

Comment: In the example you showed, I see that in B5 it is showing row 5 instead of row 2 but I want to get the previous duplicate row number and same for B7 I want to see row 3

Comment: I updated the formulas - they now show the rows of the duplicates for the first occurance of a value

Comment: This is what I was looking for however, there is a small issue- I see that in C column it doesn't recognize the very first entry as duplicate. For instance, in C5 it should show like 2,8 and in C8 it should show 2,5. The first original entry is not recognized by this formula is what I mean (row 2 in this case). Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You really should have put more effort to describe the desired output in your original question ... maybe I find time later to adjust the answer

Comment: What you did was right when you did duplicate names in row(s) however, the formula doesn't pick up all row duplicates (the very first entry, row 2).

Comment: I got it! Just had to make it >=1. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A5, $A5)>1, ROW(A5), "")  will return the row number as a second column

=CONCATENATE("Duplicates Exist in:  ",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, B2:B15)) will return those numbers back as a single cell that looks like Duplicates Exist in:  7.

Note: the above if identifies only the duplicates after the first, a slight modification would list all duplicate occurrences.

sources:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/03/02/identify-duplicates-excel/ & https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-combine-rows-into-one-cell-2/

Comment: can you please share an example so I can have an idea as to where to use the formulas? 
Thanks